# TypeScript inheritance of web components breaks while importing modules from mapped source files from dist

Tags: javascript, typescript, parceljs, native-web-component

I am trying to figure out how to bundle my JS generated code from TS files and I am facing some issues.
I have two components, where one is extending the another.

Let's keep it simple.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./public",
    "outDir": "dist",
        "paths": {
          "@js/*": ["../dist/public/javascripts/*"]
        }
  }
}
```

Just parent component:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML =
    `
    <style>
    </style>
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    `

export class Parent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }


}

window.customElements.define('my-parent', Parent)
```

and the child component:

```
import {Parent} from '@js/Parent.js' <- does not work
import {Parent} from './Parent.js' <- works fine

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML =
    `
    <style>
    </style>
    <h1>Child</h1>
    `

class Child extends Parent{

    formId = 'adventureNpcs';
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

}

window.customElements.define('my-child', Child)
```

It seems that after importing module from mapped file (generated source from dist) can't see the inheritance between them anymore, which is resulting with:

```
Property 'attachShadow' does not exist on type 'Child'.
```

Why the child is recognized while importing the module in this way:

```
import {Parent} from './Parent.js'
```

And this does not work?

```
import {Parent} from '@js/Parent.js'
```

Am I missing something? Doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on filelocations ***and*** synchronous loading, you can rely on the `CustomElementsRegistry`

You could refactor it to:

- no export needed, because `<my-parent>` is defined (or not yet) in the CustomElementsRegisrty
- `<my-child>` will be defined ***When*** `<my-parent>` has been defined
- you can still keep the separate files for components, but can load them in any order you want
- PS using a template to set `innerHTML` is bloated code and will only have a performance gain for thousand of elements. All old blogs showing this should be burned. Same goes for all not showing `super()` can be chained.

```js
customElements.whenDefined('my-parent').then(() => {
  customElements.define('my-child', class extends customElements.get('my-parent') {
   connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML += ` inside <span part="title">${this.nodeName}</span>`;
   }
  })
});

document.body.onclick = () => {
  customElements.define('my-parent', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
             .innerHTML = `<h5 part="title">${this.nodeName}</h5><slot></slot>`
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body{ font: 16px Arial } 

*:not(:defined){
  background:red;
}

*::part(title){
  /* part does not style content in NESTED shadowRoots */
  background:green;
  color:gold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Cick me to create &lt;my-parent></h2>

<my-parent><my-child>FOO</my-child></my-parent>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to solve my problem? It isn't related even to the problem which is described? Or did I missed something? I don't want the generated js filse to be in project. That's the first point and the second point is I don't want the Parent to hold the child element, I want the child element to INHERIT the parent component. It is quite different thing.

Comment: So what does ``customElements.define('my-child', class extends customElements.get('my-parent')`` do??